# Revertir lista recursivamente en C++

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos

Estoy tratando de revertir una lista recursivamente. El problema es cuando la función recursiva llega al caso base.Esta debería devolver un puntero al ultimo elemento de la lista. Si imprimo el puntero antes del retorno(dentro de la función) el valor es el correcto, pero una vez retornado el puntero apunta a el primer elemento.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node{
  int dato;
  Node * sig;
};

void insert(Node * &list,int d){
  Node * newNode=new Node();
  newNode->dato=d;
  newNode->sig=0;

  if(list==0){

    list=newNode;
    return;

  }

  newNode->sig=list;
  list=newNode;
}

void print(Node * list){
  Node * temp=list;

  while(temp!=0){

    cout<< temp->dato<<endl;
    temp=temp->sig;
  }
}

Node * reverse(Node * list){
  Node* ptr = list;

  if(list->sig!=0){
    ptr = reverse(list->sig);

    (list->sig)->sig=list;
    list->sig=0;
  }

  return ptr;
}

int main(){
  Node * l = 0; //creo la cabeza de la lista

  insert(l,3);// cargo 3 valores
  insert(l,2);
  insert(l,1);

  l=reverse(l); // la cabeza de la lista apunta al ultimo elemento retornado por reverse()

  print(l);

  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Implementación **muy** imaginativa. Pregunta **muy** interesante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Node * reverse(Node * list)
{
  if(list->sig==0)
  {
    // cout->list; Si imprimo acá el valor es el correcto
    return list; // al retornar el valor cambia
  }

  reverse(list->sig);

  (list->sig)->sig=list;
  list->sig=0;
}
```

Esta función, desde el momento en el que no finaliza `return` ya está mal implementada. Aun así vamos a analizar su comportamiento:

- `reverse(1)` -> list => 1
- `list->sig == 2` (no entra en el if)
- `reverse(2)` -> list => 2

  - `list->sig == 3` (no entra en el if)
  - `reverse(3)` -> list => 3

    - `list->sig == 0` (entra en el if)
    - `return 3`
  - (*1)
  - `list->sig->sig = list` -> 2->3->sig = 2
  - `list->sig = 0` -> 2->sig = 0
  - (no hay return) **ERROR!!!**
- `list->sig->sig = list` -> 1->2->sig = 2
- `list->sig = 0`  -> 1->sig = 0
- (no hay return) **ERROR!!!**

La teoría estaría bien... pero te falta retornar el puntero al nuevo primer elemento de la lista y ese puntero lo has perdido en (*1). Una vez has perdido dicho puntero ya no hay vuelta atrás porque la lista, al ser simple, no tienes ningún puntero que te permita acceder a dicho nodo.

¿Solución? Un par de retoques tontos:

```
Node * reverse(Node * list)
{
  Node* ptr = list;

  if(list->sig!=0)
  {
    ptr = reverse(list->sig);

    (list->sig)->sig=list;
    list->sig=0;
  }

  return ptr;
}
```

La mecánica es muy simple... el valor a retornar por la función será uno de los siguientes:

- Si el nodo actual no es el último nodo de la lista, lo que devuelva la llamada recursiva.
- Si el nodo actual es el último se devuelve dicho nodo.

De esta forma te garantizas que la función te devuelve el nodo al primer nodo de la lista invertida.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. ¿Sería correcto tambien agregar la línea return 0; ?

Comment: @juan Obviamente no porque entonces no recuperarías un puntero a un elemento de la lista

Comment: Entonces el error esta en el valor de retorno la funcion? 0 sería un int no un puntero nulo

Comment: @juan 0 es un valor... Si se almacena en un int es un número, pero si lo almacenas en un puntero es una posición de memoria

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo a qué te refieres con "[*revertir*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WOFpWlZ)" una lista ¿Te refieres a ordenarla de manera inversa?.

Sea como sea, tu recursión es inútil. La función `reverse` devuelve un puntero a `Node`, pero no usas dicho retorno para nada. Sólo devuelves un `Node` cuando has llegado al último nodo, en el resto de casos no devuelves nada y la función finaliza... lo que es un [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido).

```
Node * reverse(Node * list){
    if(list->sig==0){
        // Devuelves el nodo que no apunta a un siguiente
        // es decir: el ultimo nodo.
        return list;
    }

    // Llamas recursivamente a la funcion Y NO RECOGES EL VALOR DE RETORNO
    reverse(list->sig);

    (list->sig)->sig=list;
    list->sig=0;
} // FINALIZAS LA FUNCION SIN DEVOLVER NINGUN VALOR!!!!
```

Tus nodos están estructurados así:

[image]

Y ¿Qué está pasando?

- Llamamos a `reverse` con *NodoA*.

  1. *NodoA*`->sig` no es `0` (es *NodoB*), no se cumple el `if`.
  2. Llamas a `reverse` con *NodoA*`->sig` que es *NodoB*.

     1. *NodoB*`->sig` no es `0` (es *NodoC*), no se cumple el `if`.
     2. Llamas a `reverse` con *NodoB*`->sig` que es *NodoC*.

        1. *NodoC*`->sig` es `0` se cumple el `if`.
        2. Devuelves *NodoC*.
     3. Se descarta el valor devuelto por la llamada anterior (no se recoge).
     4. Se hace apuntar al siguiente del siguiente de *NodoB* (que es `NULL`) a *NodoB*.
     5. Se hace apuntar al siguiente de *NodoB* (que es *NodoC*) a `NULL`.
     6. Finaliza la función sin devolver nada.
  3. Se descarta el valor devuelto por la llamada anterior (no se recoge).
  4. Se hace apuntar al siguiente del siguiente de *NodoA* (que es `NULL`) a *NodoA*.
  5. Se hace apuntar al siguiente de *NodoA* (que es *NodoB*) a `NULL`.
  6. Finaliza la función sin devolver nada.
- Ese *nada* que has devuelto, que podría ser cualquier cosa<sup>1</sup>, es almacenado en `l`.
- Llamas la función `print` con lo que sea que `l` contiene.

Después de llamar a `reverse` tus nodos estarán estructurados así:

[image]

#### Sugerencias.

Deberías corregir el error en `reverse` devolviendo un valor en todas las rutas de ejecución.

No deberías mezclar conceptos, un Nodo y una Lista no son lo mismo, crea una clase Lista que contenga Nodos no trates los Nodos como si fueran una lista<sup>2</sup>. Las funciones que ya tienes creadas (`inert`, `print` y `reverse`) petenecerían a la clase Lista y los Nodos serían datos privados de la misma.

.

---

<sup>1</sup>Podría ser un puntero válido, un puntero no válido, el primer parámetro pasado a la función, las claves para entrar en El Pentágono o una dirección de memoria al azar.

<sup>2</sup>Es tan inadecuado como decir que una Bugía es un Coche, aunque los Coches tienen Bugías, las Bugías nunca serán Coches.

Comment: Gracias! No se por qué había asumido que en l se asignaba el retorno de la ultima llamada a  reverse();     :(....